# Why are getmore ops so fast from mongo shell while they are slow using the c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance

If I run a query using mongo shell that loads 10.000 documents, it starts multiple `getmore` operations to fetch all 10.000 documents from the cursor. <s>6 `getmore` operations that seem like they run in parallel, so the query executes quite fast</s>
These operations are very fast (about 200 ms time between them):

[image]

```
db.coll
    .find({
        "start": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2018-06-01T00:00:00+02:00"),
            "$lte": ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00+02:00"),
        },
        "state": {
            $in: ["OK"]
        }
    })
    .limit(10000)
    .toArray()
```

But if I run the same query using the C# driver, <s>that only uses 1 `getmore` at a time until all documents are retrieved</s>
the time between `getmore` operations significantly higher (1-2 seconds):

[image]

This of course slows down the query when executed from C#. Is there something I am doing wrong in C#?

```
List<Tb> tbs = new List<Tb>();
List<ObjectId> tbIds = new List<ObjectId>();

if (keys != null && keys.Count > 0)
{
    tbFilter = tbBuilder.In("categories.values.key", keys);
                  
    var tbProjection = Builders<Tb>.Projection.Include(t => t.Id);
    List<TbIdOnly> tbOnlyIds = await context._tbs
        .Find(tbFilter)
        .Project<TbIdOnly>(tbProjection)
        .ToListAsync();
    tbIds = tbOnlyIds.Select(t => t.Id).ToList();
    filter = filter & builder.In(t => t.IdTb, tbIds);
}

if (startTime != null)
    filter = filter & builder.Gte(t => t.TsStart, startTime);
if (endTime != null)
    filter = filter & builder.Lte(t => t.TsStart, endTime);
if (status != null && status.Count > 0)
    filter = filter & builder.In(t => t.State, status);

var query = context._trs
    .Find(filter, new FindOptions() {BatchSize = maxNumValues})
    .Limit(maxNumValues);

Console.WriteLine($"Running query:\n {query.ToString()}");

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

List<Tr> trs = new List<Tr>();

using (var cursor = await query.ToCursorAsync())
{
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
             var cursorRuns = cursor.Current;
             trs.AddRange(cursorRuns);
             Console.WriteLine($"Fetched batch of trs.. {cursor.Current.Count()}");
        }
}
sw.Stop();
```

Comment: My guess is the answer is "because it is implemented differently".

Comment: So it may be impossible to return 10.000 of my documents in an acceptable amount of time using the c# driver?

Comment: I have a similar problem with my node.js driver. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

`getMore` operations do not provide the starting position - they return the next batch of the cursor. As such it is not possible to have more than one `getMore` running on the same cursor at a time.

You made a mistake somewhere in your analysis.

Comment: Thank you, I agree, I misunderstood the first graph I showed in the question. They do not run in parallel, but they are much faster when the query is executed from shell than from C#. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use command monitoring (e.g. [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring), apply to your driver) to verify the time to execute the queries is the same in your driver and in the shell. If not, use command monitoring to retrieve exact commands sent and issue them in the shell.

On the sending side, drivers may have more things they are doing than the shell, for example:

- Managing and using implicit sessions
- Connection pools

Note that the drivers connect asynchronously (creating a Client object doesn't connect in foreground) while the shell connects synchronously. When you are benchmarking a driver vs the shell you need to ensure you already have the driver connected to and monitoring all servers, otherwise you are including server connection and monitoring time in the driver time but not in the shell's time.

On both sending and receiving side but especially on the receiving side, the driver generally deserializes the server response into language objects. Some languages are more efficient at this, others less so. Benchmark retrieving documents with simple fields like integers vs complex fields like arrays and times.

If you have application-level overrides for serialization or deserialization, that would increase the time to "execute a query" substantially.